# How to mouse over for element Javascript + Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Sup, how can i mouse over for element
Javascript + Selenium

```
await driver.actions({ bridge: true }).moveToElement(task).perform()
```

log says : TypeError: driver.actions(...).moveToElement is not a function

```
await driver.actions({ bridge: true }).moveToElement(task).perform()
```

Comment: ```
    await driver.actions({ bridge: true }).move({duration:100,origin:task,x:0,y:0}).perform();
 ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try -> `actions.moveToElement(elementToMove).perform();`

Comment: it should be actions.moveToElement(elementToMove).build().perform();

Comment: Without `.build()` for me also works.